Eclipse File Search IDE issue
Getting this error on Eclipse 2024-03 when using file search Ctrl+H;
Text Search
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'
An internal error occurred during: "File Search Worker".
'byte[] org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.readNBytes(int)'

Things I've tried;
Reinstalling Eclipse from my zip package, Clean/Refresh/Update Maven Project commands.
Note;
Using the zipped package, running on jdk 1.8, using lombok.jar.
I want to know where else I should be looking, please feel free to ask for other details as well.

Is this reproducible with the current Eclipse version 2024-09?

Actually you aren't using Java 8 because 2024-03 won't run on that - you are most likely using the JDK built-in to Eclipse.

this is the java -version response on my device
java version "1.8.0_421"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_421-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.421-b09, mixed mode)
compliance level 1.8
jdk1.8 also selected as installed JRE
my environment variables ECLIPSE_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and MAVEN_HOME are also set to the proper directories and are set in Path as well.
As for 2024-09 we haven't been advised to use that yet.

What java -version says is not really relevant to what Eclipse uses - most Eclipse downloads contain their own version of Java which they use regardless of any installed Java. As I said Eclipse 2024-03 will simply not run on Java 8 as it uses many newer features not in 8. You may be using Java 8 to run your code but that is not what Eclipse itself is using.

I believe the IFile.readNBytes method is new in Eclipse 2024-09, so there seems to be something wrong here - but would probably be fixed by using 2024-09.

I understand. Will try your recommendations, thanks!

IFile.readNBytes(int) has been introduced by this comment in Eclipse 2024-09. There have been no issues reported about readNBytes so far.

AFAIR Eclipse 2024-09 doesn't make use of your Java 8 to run itself, instead it requires Java 21 which is built-in and usually used.

Do the entries for these errors in the Error Log View have a stack trace that can be shared? Is this reproducible with the current Eclipse version, 2024-09, without Lombok?

Same happen to me when I installed Spring tools 4, in 2024-06

@Tupac Which version of Spring Tools? And does updating Eclipse fix it? If yes, please make sure it has been reported to Spring Tools with the error details: please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into the issue report formatted as code. If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce the issue.

Could be related to the CoPilot plug-in issue https://github.com/Genuitec/Copilot4Eclipse-community/discussions/23

Hi @howlger , I been trying to keep clean Eclipse 2024-06 and works, when I install anything for marketplace (anything that I use) the search is crashing. I try with enhance class decompiler, Spring tools that I already sayed, Darkest dark theme, anything makes search crash. Yeah with 09 works fine (with the plug ins too) but it seems that with 2024-09 I can't compile anything under java 8, I have a couple of projects with 1.5,1.6,1.7

As @LeibRozenblium already mentioned, this is a confirmed issue of the Copilot4Eclipse plugin. The darkest dark theme plugin is also from the same vendor and patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause strange issues that seem to be unrelated and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). Your issue has only been reported so far for plugins from this one vendor only. The Eclipse Marketplace is a catalog and does not offer anything to install itself.

Also reported an issue to m2e: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1886

@LeibRozenblium Can what you say be reproduced with a fresh installation and a fresh workspace? There have been a couple of such strange issues caused by Genuitec plugins using loadtime weaving in the past. Please help to avoid that bugs from Genuitec are wasting the time of open source developers once again. And Genuitec has already confirmed that the bug is caused by them, as usual with blaming others for their own mistakes ("there is a loose specification on the eclipse search.core plugin").

Updating eclipse to 2024-09 fixed this for me.

+1. If you don't have time to do fresh setup, you can do eclipse>Help>Check for Updates and update eclipse to latest. This solved the issue for me.
